# Заполнение пустого списка с клавиатуры

Tags: kotlin, list

Нужна помощь в решении задания с заполнением пустого списка с клавиатуры через цикл. Нужно сохранить в список N телефонных номеров, каждый номер представляет из себя строку. Список вынесен в отдельную функцию, функция принимает число и возвращает строку

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        println("Enter N")
        val N: Int = readLine()?.toIntOrNull() ?: return
}

fun useIterator (N: Int): String {

    val emptyList = mutableListOf<String>()
    val iterator = emptyList.iterator()
   if (N==555) {
       break
   } else {
        iterator.next()
        iterator.add()
         }
  return (emptyList.toString())
}
```

пробовал через forEach, но тоже не разобрался как это сделать

Comment: [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1320320/edit), пожалуйста, ваш вопрос, приведите в порядок код, чтобы его хотя бы можно было скопировать, запустить и посмотреть, что не так. Прочитайте о том, [как создать минимальный, но самодостаточный пример, демонстрирующий проблему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Посмотрите [примеры](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/control-flow.html), как писать циклы на языке Котлин.

Answer (score 0):

Моя версия решения задачи, используя `Scanner`:

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main() {
    print("Введите n: ")
    val n: Int = readLine()?.toIntOrNull() ?: return
    println(fillList(n))
}

fun fillList(n: Int): String {
    val list: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    println("Введите номера: ")
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        list.add(scanner.nextLine())
        if (list.size == n) {
            break
        }
    }
    return list.toString()
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, функция делает то что нужно, но я хотел на чистом котлине без импорта с java и кажется у меня получилось
`fun fillList(N: Int): String {

     val numberList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

     println("Введите номера: ")

    for (i in 0 until N) {

        val iterator = numberList.listIterator()

        iterator.hasNext()

        iterator.add(readLine()!!)

    }`